# Nodejs - Correct way to iterate through nested JSON array

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

Consider the following sample JSON array:

```
[{
    info: {
        refOne: 'refOne',
        refTwo: [{
            refOne: 'refOne',
            refTwo: 'refTwo'
        }]
    }
}, {
    info: {
        refOne: 'refOne',
        refTwo: [{
            refOne: 'refOne',
            refTwo: 'refTwo'
        }]
    }
}]
```

The above JSON is a simple representation of a database query response, What is the correct way within Nodejs to loop through each 'refTwo' array within the parent info array?

sudo example:
 for each item in sample JSON
  for each refTwo item in current item
    do something

I have a suspicion that the 'async' lib may be required here but some advice is much appreciated.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is a simple javascript question:

```
var o = [...];

var fn = function (e){
    e.refOne...
    e.refTwo...
};

o.forEach (function (e){
    e.info.refTwo.forEach (fn);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for prompt response.

Answer (score 2):

You could use [underscore](http://underscorejs.org/) or [lodash](http://lodash.com/) to do it in a functional way.

For example have a look at [Collections.each](http://underscorejs.org/#each) and [Collections.map](http://underscorejs.org/#map):

```
var _ = require('underscore');

var result = // your json blob here

var myRefs = _.map(results, function(value, key) {
  return value.info.refTwo;
};
// myRefs contains the two arrays from results[0].info.refTwo from results[1].info.refTwo now

// Or with each:
_.each(results, function(value, key) {
  console.log(value.info.refTwo);
}

// Naturally you can nest, too:
_.each(results, function(value, key) {
  _.each(value.info.refTwo, function(innerValue) { // the key parameter is optional
    console.log(value);
  }
}
```

Edit: You can of course use the forEach method suggested by Gabriel Llamas, however I'd recommend having a look at underscore nonetheless.

Comment: Thanks for providing alternative methods. I shall follow up and have a read.